# PatIndex match regex

Tags: sql-server, regex

I've been struggling to find a regex that using PatIndex would match anything and including to the first dot. For example `dbo.` in `dbo.Table`. Any help?

The best I had was `select PatIndex('%_.%', 'dbo.Table')` but that leaves the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upto my knoweldge, there is no need to use `_` in the pattern, the PATINDEX always returns the index of first matching word or character.

Try this:

```
select PatIndex('%.%', 'dbo.Table')
-- output: 4
select PatIndex('%.%', 'servername.dbo.Table')
-- output: 11
```